# Vectors and simultaneous equations?

Tags: geometry, vectors

[image]

I was looking at this question and managed to find expressions for most of the sides (I also found the vector OM, but I am unsure what to do next). I am thinking that you need to set up some simultaneous equation with ON or AP, but can anyone tell me how they would solve this?

Comment: you could just use menelaus's theorem for OMB.

Comment: How would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\overrightarrow{ON}=k\mathbf{b}$, we have:
$$
\overrightarrow{AP}={4\over7}{\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}\over2}-
\mathbf{a}={2\over7}\mathbf{b}-{5\over7}\mathbf{a},
\quad
\overrightarrow{AN}=\overrightarrow{ON}-\mathbf{a}=k\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}.
$$
But $\overrightarrow{AN}=t\overrightarrow{AP}$ for some $t$, that is:
$$
k\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}={2\over7}t\mathbf{b}-{5\over7}t\mathbf{a}.
$$
We thus get: $t={7\over5}$ and $k={2\over5}$. Finally:
$$
ON:NB=k:(1-k)=2:3.
$$